# You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the serve command. Error on running a dynamic web project

Tags: eclipse, angular

I am trying to make a dynamic web project using angular 2. I did so by creating dynamic web project in eclipse EE neon. After that I right clicked on project -> show in-> terminal. After this I ran `ng serve` command but below error is coming.

> You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the serve command

Angular cli is installed at global level(C drive). My workspace is in D drive.

I also tried to install angular CLI at Drive.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: You shoul'd show us the structure of your project. Does your project contain an angular-cli.json file ?

Comment: are you sure you are executing `ng serve` on your project folder?

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? Are you inside an Angular CLI project when executing ng serve? Have you even created an Angular CLI project? Have you read the instructions of Angular CLI on how to create an Angular CLI project? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: No. I don't have angular-cli.json file in my project structure.
Do i have to add it manually? If yes, from where will i get this.
If no, then how to add this in while creating dynamic web project from file->new project tab.
Sorry i am new to this.

Comment: "dynamic web project" is the eclipse lingo for "Java EE based web application". It has absolutely nothing to do with Angular and Angular CLI. To create an Angular project with Angular CLI, you read the instructions of Angular CLI. I already linked to them.

Comment: Yes you are right @JB Nizet. But when i try to create angular project rather than dynamic web project, the cli works perfectly.
And it also display the welcome to app text.
There might be some problem with dynamic web project.

Comment: There is none. What is wrong is your assumption that creating a dynamic web project in Eclipse will create an Angular CLI project. Just as wrong as thinking that when asking for a bread in a bakery, you'll get out with a new fruit basket.

Comment: So can you please guide me with how to make a dynamic web project in eclipse which will use angular 2 as front end and JAVA as back end.
It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem into a project which was create on mac and after get it through git in windows 10. I solve it with this:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

You seems not have installed npm modules in your project or in that directory location from where you are getting this error. 
Run **npm install** from command line on the same directory location, and then try ng build or Ng serve ..

Comment: Thanks for reply kamlesh.But this command displays following error.
**npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\WORKSPACES\Eclipse-NeonEE-Workspace-java8\S
upportPortal\package.json'**

It is seraching for package.json. But this project is not a angular project yet. How to make this dynamic web project into angular 2 project where i can use java as backend.

Comment: yes, you are running the command wrong directory, did you have installed Angular Quick Start? If Not follow this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html ... install Angular quick start first then run  **npm install** command

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the legacy ng in like this: `node_modules\.bin\ng update`.